# sort array without altering null or empty places using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have some arrays all of equal lengths and four null values are present at random positions for each those arrays and i need to sort those array of numbers, provided the position of null is not altered.

For example, My arrays:

```
var arr1 = [6, 3, null, 5, null, 4, null, null];
var arr2 = [null, 7, 4, null, 6, null, 5, null];
```

Expected output should be: (null positions are not altered)

```
var arr1 = [3, 4, null, 5, null, 6, null, null];
var arr2 = [null, 4, 5, null, 6, null, 7, null];
```

Please Help advise or suggest somecode in the below function so to acheive this requirement in javascript

```
function sortByNotalterNull(arr) {

 //somecode here

 return arr;
};
sortByNotalterNull(arr1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a helper array for the not `null` indices and another for the numbers, sort them and apply them back on the previously stored indices of the original array.

```js
const sort = array => {
        let indices = [];

        array
            .filter((v, i) => v !== null && indices.push(i))
            .sort((a, b) => a - b)
            .forEach((v, i) => array[indices[i]] = v);
        return array;
    };

console.log(...sort([6, 3, null, 5, null, 4, null, null]));
console.log(...sort([null, 7, 4, null, 6, null, 5, null]));
```